# Issue with JSON.stringify adding a extra \ and "" to my Json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, serialization, deserialization

Hi I am creating using Javascript an array of object with a key and a value using the following code.

```
ValuesArray.push({ key: $(this).attr('someattribute'), value: $(this).val() });
```

As a result I have am array of object like this:

```
key:29; value: 'Country'
Key:12; value: '4,3,5'
```

when I am trying to stringify it and send that JSON in a post I am having a wrong formatted JSON with \ and " in places that I dont want so when I try to desirales that JSON as a JObject on codebehind with C# I am having trouble. How can I create a clean JSON using the stringify

```
var jObject = JSON.stringify(ValuesArray);
```

My JSON now which is wrong is:

```
{
  "JObject": "[{\"key\":\"29\",\"value\":\"Country\"},  {\"key\":\"30\",\"value\":\"4,3,5\"}]"
}
```

I would like to have a JSON object like this

```
{
  "JObject": [{"key":"29","value":"Country"},{"key":"30","value":"4,3,5"}]
}
```

without the quotes around the `[]` and the character `\`

Any good idea to solve it.

Thank you

More detail this how I am sending the JSON to my API
this is how I am sending the JSON to my Web API:

```
function PostAPIRequest(address) {

           var jObject = JSON.stringify(ValuesArray);

           var responseJson = null;
           $.ajax({
               url: address,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { JObject: jObject },
               success: function (data) {
                   responseJson = data
                   ProcessDataResponse(responseJson);
                   //TODO: REFRESH THE DATA GRID
               },
               error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   //TODO redirect to the error page and send error email there.
                   alert(xhr.status);
                   alert(thrownError);
               }
           })
       }
```

and this how I am receiving it in my API controller

```
...
  // POST api/datavalues/5


   public string Post(int id, JObject  value)
    {
        var temp = value;

...
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like you are placing a string as the value in your map.  You should do something like:

`var objMap = {"JObject" : ValuesArray};`
`var json = JSON.stringify(objMap)`

What's happening is you are double json encoding your values array - note that your "invalid" JSON value is actually a JSON string rather than the array that you want.

**EDIT**
It looks like you are sticking in JSON strings of maps into an Array and then stringifying that.  Here's a jsfiddle that should help you get what you are looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/4G5nF/

In your post request, try this

```
var jObject = {"JObject" : ValuesArray};
$.ajax({   url: address,
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: jObject,
           success: function (data)  { .. }});
```

Note the change in the data attribute.  That is a value that is automatically JSONified for you.

Comment: Thanks SB but it didnt work it create this JSON  {
  "{\"JObject\":": {
    "{\"key\":\"20\",\"value\":\"ddd\"},{\"key\":\"21\",\"value\":\"4,5,13,14,15,\"}]}": ""
  }
}  I am still having the characters \ and no a valid JSON formatted to deserialize in my Web API

Comment: It is interesting that now I get a clean JSON but with a lot of spaces and line return

Comment: This is wrong, this is not the reason it happens. Its because the JSON string created is: [{"key":"29","value":"Country"},{"key":"30","value":"4,3,5"}]. But when you try to post it to the php, the string you want to send gets placed inside another string, with seporator ". Which means your string cant contain ", and therefore jquery turns them in to \"

Answer (score 22):

```
const config = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(config)))
```

**"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"**

Comment: It's hard to detect at times...

Comment: `typeof obj` and `console.log("%o", obj)` could help identifying if an object is a string or an Object...

Answer (score 12):

May be you have an old `prototype` library. 
As I remove it, bug has disappeared

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js