# Backbonejs model save putting double quotes around array in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, backbone.js

I'm doing a pretty basic Backbonejs model.save:

```
this.model.save(null, {
    success: function(model, response)
    {

    },

    error: function(model, response)
    {

    }
});
```

The model contains some string attributes, and an array of objects.  When I look at the raw ajax request that Backbone makes (using jQuery ajax, I believe), it wraps the array in double quotes.  This causes my endpoint to try to parse the value as a string, rather than an array:

```
{
    id: 108,
    name: "My model",
    questions: "[{"id": 100, "name": "question 1"}, {"id": 101, "name": "question 2"}]"
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before?  Is there a way to force Backbone/jQuery to not wrap the array in quotes, i.e.:

```
questions: [{"id": 100, "name": "question 1"}, {"id": 101, "name": "question 2"}]
```

**Update**, backbone's sync function calls JSON.stringify on the output of model.toJSON, and JSON.stringify is what is adding those quotes.  For example:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({name: 'test1', animals: ['horse', 'pig']}));
```

Outputs:

```
{"name":"test1","animals":"[\"horse\", \"pig\"]"}
```

Comment: What is your `model.toJSON()`?

Comment: It does NOT contain the quotes

Comment: You could try setting a breakpoint (or typing `debugger;`) here: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1407 I'm guessing if you stepped through that code, you might find where it's happening.

Comment: That is not even a valid string and this is not likely to happen. Please share a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: @TJ right, but that is exactly what backbone is hitting my endpoint with, hence the issue

Comment: @Clayton Well like I said, backbone was **not** causing the issue. No one could find an answer without an MCVE since you didn't even tag the question with prototype.

Answer (score 0):

We are using an old version of prototype.js, v.1.6.0.3, which was causing this issue.
Adding the following resolved it:

```
if(window.Prototype) 
{
    // Disable prototype's buggy version of toJSON for arrays
    delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
}
```

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20331694/1449
and: [JSON.stringify() array bizarreness with Prototype.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710586/json-stringify-array-bizarreness-with-prototype-js)